# Amazon ECS Application level monitoring and instance autohealing without ELB

Tags: http, amazon-web-services, containers, devops, amazon-ec2

i'm deploying and app to Amazon ECS and need some advice on application level monitoring (periodic HTTP 200 and/or body match). Usually i place it behind an ELB and i am sure that my ELB will take action if it sees too many HTTP errors.
However this time it's a very low budget project and the budget for the ELB should be avoided (also consider this is going to work with only one instance as the userbase is very limited).

What strategies could i adopt to grant that the application is alive (kill instance and restart in case of too many app errors)? Regarding the instance i know about AWS autohealing but that's infrastructure.

Obviously one of the problems is that not having an ELB i must bind the DNS to an EIP....so reassigning it it's crucial.
And obviously the solution should not involve any other EC2 instance, external services are acceptable but keeping it all inside AWS would be great.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Monitoring of ECS is important to improve the importance of your site. If you still think there could be issues related to deployment on AWS, I suggest to practice auto-scaling feature of AWS.

You can scale up ECS when needed and release it when not required.

Nagios is another open source monitoring tool that you can leverage. Easy to install and configure.